# Close pop up form once submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help me out here, i have a form which pop ups after a min on a video page, i want the form to close by itself once its submitted so the video could continue, how this is possible with jQuery?

this is my form

```
 <ul class="mktLblLeft">
            <div class="txt-fld">
                <label>First Name:</label><span class="mktInput"><input class="mktFormText" id="Email" maxlength="255" name="24132" tabindex="1" type="text" value="" />
                </span></li>

                <label>Last Name:</label><span class="mktInput"><input class="mktFormTex" id="FirstName" maxlength="255" name="24134" tabindex="2" type="text" value="" /></span></li>
               <label>Email Address:</label><span class="mktInput"><input class="mktFormText" id="LastName" maxlength="255" name="24136" tabindex="3" type="text" value="" />
              </div>
              <div class="btn-fld">
              <button type="submit">Sign Up &raquo;</button>
```

i have tried this code, is there something wrong with this?

```
function closeSelf(){
// do something

if(condition satisfied){
   alert("conditions satisfied, submiting the form.");
   document.forms['certform'].submit();
   window.close();
}else{
   alert("conditions not satisfied, returning to form");    
}
```

}

Comment: I would imagine you have some code that handles submitting the form... should be able to add it there, no?

Comment: @Bartdude i have added the code i tried

Comment: @JasonP i have event handler script and i could add it there. i am looking for the right function to do this.

Comment: Is your popup form an actual new window that pops up? If so, _after_ the submit, have some javascript that calls `window.close()`.

Comment: @JasonP  I am using the leanModal jQuery plugin, its not small box that pops up after 2 min asking user to sign up for newsletter. you could see the plugin here http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/

Comment: @rockydude Then `form.submit()` won't work, as that will refresh the page, and `window.close()` won't work as that will close the entire window, not just the modal. You'll need to use ajax to send the form data, and look at the plugin's api documentation to learn how to close the dialog programatically.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to to this would be to use hide() when the button is clicked.

```
<button type="submit" onlick="$('#myForm').hide()">Sign Up &raquo;</button>
```

Assuming this is inside a `<form id="myForm">`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery AJAX solution:

```
jQuery('button#yourSubmitButton').on('click', function(event) {
    // prevent normal submit
    event.preventDefault();

    // call ajax submit
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "bin/yourprocess.php",
        success: function() {
            // fadeout the form
            jQuery('.mktLblLeft').fadeOut();
        },
        error: function() {
            // give feedback to user
            alert('something went wrong!');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry i am not good with this, so i am changing  url: "bin/yourprocess.php", with my link and the button # right

Comment: Just give your button an id or class. just like <button type="submit" id="yourSubmitButton">Sign Up &raquo;</button> and yes,switch url to the forms action.